# MONGOuri is already string but gives error as MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"

Tags: node.js, string, mongodb, mongoose

I have keys.js in config folder and instead of .env files I'm using it as storing imp credentials.
**I haven't kept my password here**
 MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.

ss of console.log(typeof(keys.mongoURI));
[ss of console.log(typeof(keys.mongoURI))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdUfS.png)

**config/keys.js** file

```
const mongoURI = "mongodb+srv://MERN_dev:<password>@cluster0.jl831.mongodb.net/ED_MERN?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

module.exports = {
    mongoURI,
    other parameters
}
```

Now in my **data/mongodb.js** file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys  = require('../config/keys');
//console.log(typeof(keys));
console.log(typeof(keys.mongoURI));
const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(keys.MONGO_URI, {
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useNewUrlParser: true                    
        })

        console.log(`Mongoose connected on port ${conn.connection.host}`);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

module.exports = connectDB;
```

At last my index.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./data/mongodb');

connectDB();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started at ${PORT}!`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's just typo instead of keys.MONGO_URI it's keys.mongoURI

Comment: Please directly edit your question so that others can help you better. Once it is done, you may want to delete this answer.